# Browser rendering the EJS code as normal HTML text

Tags: node.js, templates, backend, ejs

I'm trying to create a dynamic page using EJS but it is not working quite like a template. Instead, it's rendering the EJS code as normal HTML text in the browser.

I was about send data to this EJS file but when I took a look at the page, I got my EJS code render as html text.

This is the ejs code:

```html
<body id="app">

  <form class="container" action="/submit" method="post">
    <div class="horizontal-container">
      <h3>
        Total Score:
        <span id="score">
          <%= locals.totalScore ? totalScore : "0" %>
        </span>
      </h3>

    </div>

    <h1 id="countryFlag">
      <%=question.flag %>
    </h1>
    <div class="answer-container">
      <input type="text" name="answer" id="userInput" placeholder="Name the country" autofocus autocomplete="off">

    </div>
    <button type="submit">SUBMIT<% if(locals.wasCorrect){ %>
        <span class="checkmark">✔</span>
        <% } else if (locals.wasCorrect===false) { %>
          <span class="cross" id="error">✖</span>
          <% } %>
    </button>
  </form>


  <script>
    var wasCorrect = "<%= locals.wasCorrect %>";
    console.log(wasCorrect)
    if (wasCorrect === "false") {
      alert('Game over! Final best score: <%= locals.totalScore %>');
      document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = '<a href="/" class="restart-button">Restart</a>'
    }

  </script>
```

This is what I am getting:

```
current score <%= counter %>
<%= question %>
Enter The Name Of Country ["a input block here"]
SUBMIT<% if(locals.wascorrect){ %> ✔ <% } else if (locals.wascorrect===false) { %> ✖ <% } %>
<% if(locals.wascorrect){ %> <% if(wascorrect == false) { %> <% } %> <% } %>
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior that you are seeing is the expected behavior. The template first needs to be compiled to HTML before viewing. If you simply view the template file in a browser, it will show the uncompiled version.

This is typically how you should be using EJS in a node.js environment:

```js
let template = ejs.compile(str, options);
template(data);
// => Rendered HTML string

ejs.render(str, data, options);
// => Rendered HTML string

ejs.renderFile(filename, data, options, function(err, str){
    // str => Rendered HTML string
});
```

You can try out the EJS CLI to test your template. Feed it a template file and a data file, and specify an output file.

```
ejs ./template_file.ejs -f data_file.json -o ./output.html
```

Reference: https://ejs.co/#docs